# getting a length of a string from a variable array java

Tags: java

Im a student learning Java and this is part of my program and it is supposed to get the length of a string but the strings are all in an array.  I try to run this in eclipse and it says i get an error where it says`length = name[x].length()` can someone let me know if there is a way to fix this

```
public class GuessName
{

    Random random = new Random();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] name = new String[10];
    int x,length;
    char guess1,guess2,guess3;

    public void names()
    {
        name[0] = "MARK";
        name[1] = "CHARLIE";
        name[2] = "MEG";
        name[3] = "KYLE";
        name[4] = "JUSTIN";
        name[5] = "KATARINA";
        name[6] = "JOEL";
        name[7] = "KEVIN";
        name[8] = "MICHAEL";
        name[9] = "JENNA";
        name[10] = "GREG";
    }

    public void start()
    {
        x = random.nextInt(10);
        length = name[x].length();
    }
```

Comment: What error does it say you get?! And why do you think it says that?

Comment: Note that the `names()` method will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at defaultpackage.GuessName.start(GuessName.java:38)
 at defaultpackage.GuessName.main(GuessName.java:44)

Comment: Adding to what ZouZou said, you are adding 11 elements to an array that can hold upto 10.

Comment: You seem to be calling `start()` before calling `names()`.

Comment: Does names() actually get called from somewhere?

Comment: Ah you're right Sotirios Delimanolis I didn't call names() in my program, thanks everyone

Comment: You can just do things like `String[] names = { "name1", "name2"};`. Then use `names.length` to get the number of strings in the array.

Comment: Also remove `name[10] = "GREG";`your array size is 10.

Comment: Dude.  You are in eclipse.  You have a debugger.  DEBUG, man, DEBUG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array, as follows:

```
String[] name = new String[10];
```

The number between the `[]` represents the size of the array. In your example, your array has a size of 10 meaning your array has 10 indexes which are `[0,9]` (because indexes start at 0). The last line of your `names()` method is:

```
name[10] = "GREG";
```

Do you know where I'm getting at?

Also, what does your `main` method look like? If you're receiving a `NullPointerException` it probably means you are calling `start()` before `names()`.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the parts that was problematic. Also, you are trying to initialize 11 names as opposed to 10. Please note that arrays index starts at 0. I don't know why you have scanner object in there but you can use this block to complete your code.

```
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class GuessName {



 //   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] name = new String[10];
    int x,length;
    char guess1,guess2,guess3;

    public GuessName()
    {
        name[0] = "MARK";
        name[1] = "CHARLIE";
        name[2] = "MEG";
        name[3] = "KYLE";
        name[4] = "JUSTIN";
        name[5] = "KATARINA";
        name[6] = "JOEL";
        name[7] = "KEVIN";
        name[8] = "MICHAEL";
        name[9] = "JENNA";
       // name[10] = "GREG";
    }

    public void start()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        this.x = random.nextInt(10);
        this.length = name[this.x].length();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuessName gn = new GuessName();

        gn.start();

        System.out.println("The name is: "+gn.name[gn.x]+" and the length is: "+ gn.x);
    } }
```